# How to join / combine two arrays to concatenate into one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to combine 2 arrays in JavaScript into one.

```
var lines = new Array("a","b","c");
lines = new Array("d","e","f");
```

This is a quick example, I want to be able to combine them so that when the second line is read the 4th element in the array would return "d"

How would I do this?

Comment: Same question, more (detailed) answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/

Comment: @David All simple questions have more answers, because more people google them (or ::shivers:: use the site's built-in search feature).

Comment: @ignis This is not a duplicate. That question is specifically asking about removing duplicates in the resulting array. It is more specific, and this question is much more general.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

```
var a = ['a','b','c'];
var b = ['d','e','f'];
var c = a.concat(b); //c is now an an array with: ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
console.log( c[3] ); //c[3] will be 'd'
```

Comment: @Matt yes because its just an array it doesn't track its contents.

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate an array of arrays - i.e. for [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],..] to become [1,2,3,4,5,6,..]?

Comment: @geotheory check underscorejs there is a reduce fonction for that underscorejs.org ;)

Comment: old post, but for anyone googling now, @geotheory's question has a simple answer: `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])`

Comment: with **es6**  : `c=a.push(...b)`

Comment: You can also do:    const newArr = [...arr1, ...arr2];

Comment: For anyone wanting to use the syntax `c=a.push(...b)`, if you need to check its [compatibility with different browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=javascript%20spread) or if you want more information on `...`, it's called the spread operator or, more generally, [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: I imagine the actual answer is the fastest method?

Comment: @geotheory [`[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]].flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Comment: @JFFIGK No, quite the opposite, it is the slowest method. The fastest is via spread operator - see my answer.

Answer (score 21):

Using modern JavaScript syntax - [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const b = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

const c = [...a, ...b]; // c = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

It is also the fastest way to concatenate arrays in JavaScript today.

Comment: Helpful (+1) but got a source or at least an argument for the "fastest way" claim?

Answer (score 3):

Speed test using local nodejs v16.4.
Object Spread is 3x faster.

<sub>ObjectCombining.js</sub>

```js
export const ObjectCombining1 = (existingArray, arrayToAdd) => {
  const newArray = existingArray.concat(arrayToAdd);
  return newArray;
};

export const ObjectCombining2 = (existingArray, arrayToAdd) => {
  const newArray = [ ...existingArray, ...arrayToAdd ]
  return newArray
};
```

<sub>ObjectCombining.SpeedTest.js</sub>

```js
import Benchmark from 'benchmark';

import * as methods from './ObjectCombining.js';

let suite = new Benchmark.Suite();

const existingArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const arrayToAdd = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

Object.entries(methods).forEach(([name, method]) => {
  suite = suite.add(name, () => method(existingArray, arrayToAdd));

  console.log(name, '\n', method(existingArray, arrayToAdd),'\n');
});

suite
  .on('cycle', (event) => {
    console.log(`  ${event.target}`);
  })
  .on('complete', function () {
    console.log(`\n ${this.filter('fastest').map('name')} is fastest.\n`);
  })
  .run({ async: false });
```

<sub>Result</sub>
[image: results]

Comment: Can you add `existingArray.push(...arrayToAdd)` test, please?

Comment: @vitaly-t or, [given that](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) the benchmark is [rather useless](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html) - don't.