# "concat" does not join JavaScript arrays together?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm running the following code on Webkit:

```
var scriptElements = document.scripts;
var scriptUrls = [];
// URL matching
var regexp = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/i;
for (var i = 0; i < scriptElements.length; i++) {
    element = scriptElements[i];
    var urls = element.innerHTML.match(regexp);
    console.log('local', urls);
    scriptUrls.concat(urls);
    console.log('global', scriptUrls);
}
```

I see non-empty arrays printed after 'local' but the 'global' always stays as an empty array. What's going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803604/javascript-array-concat-not-working-why , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975170/javascript-how-to-join-combine-two-arrays-to-concatenate-into-one-array?rq=1

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`.concat` creates a new Array. You need to overwrite the old one.

```
scriptUrls = scriptUrls.concat(urls);
```

---

Or if you want to keep the original `scriptUrls` Array, you can `.push()` the values in.

```
scriptUrls.push.apply(scriptUrls, urls);
```

This uses `.apply()` to convert `urls` into individual arguments passed to `.push()`. This way the content of `urls` is added to `scriptUrls` as individual items.

---

Also, note that `.concat()` *flattens* the Array. If you wanted an Array of Arrays, then you'd use `scriptUrls.push(urls)`.

Comment: That's right, people often misunderstand JS in this aspect. Most array and string methods require an assignment to make the changes, such as `replace` or `concat` but other's don't such as `splice` for example.

Comment: @user1689607 - Yup, realized that about 10 seconds after I posted my comment.

Comment: @elclanrs: I agree. I think `.splice` and `.reverse` are the only Array methods that modify the original. And no String methods do of course since strings are immutable.

Comment: Nowadays there's `scriptUrls.push(...urls);` rather than `.push.apply`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73570026/6243352) for a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

> concat does not alter this or any of the arrays provided as arguments but instead returns a "one level deep" copy that contains copies of the same elements combined from the original arrays.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat