# Combining arrays from dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following structure:

```
ley objects = {
   key1: [1, 2, 3],
   key2: [3,4,6],
   key3: [5, 6, 7],
}
```

How can I combine those arrays keeping any duplicates so I will have `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7]`? I have tried `concat` but I cannot seem to find a way to do so. I have many more keys so it has to be some loop:

My attempt so far:

```
let arr = []
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(objects)){ 
    arr.concat(value);
}
```

Would there be a possible way to avoid this loop?

Comment: You mentioned you've "*tried `concat`*" - can you include that attempt here, so that the community might be able to point out where your current approach is flawed?

Comment: @esqew - my bad, added my attempt

Comment: Why does 6 appear 3 times in your output? What happened to 5?

Comment: `.concat()` produces a new array, so you need to assign it: `arr = arr.concat(value)`

Comment: Related: [Javascript Array Concat not working. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12803604) and [JavaScript: How to join / combine two arrays to concatenate into one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3975170)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could flat the values from the array.

```js
let object = { key1: [1, 2, 3], key2: [3, 4, 6], key3: [5, 6, 7] },
    result = Object.values(object).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Really awesome answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax.

```js
const obj = {
  key1: [1, 2, 3],
  key2: [3, 4, 6],
};

const result = [...obj.key1, ...obj.key2];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, I'd use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) in conjunction with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const obj = {
  key1: [1, 2, 3],
  key2: [3, 4, 6],
};

const result = Object.values(obj).flat();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is same as Nina's answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.concat(),Array.prototype.reduce() and Object.values()`.

```js
const obj = {
    key1: [1, 2, 3],
    key2: [3, 4, 6],
    key3: [5, 6, 7]
};

const result = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item), []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you aim not only to merge the arrays but also to sort them as per your output. In this case, you can loop through the keys and push them in one array. After that, you can sort them by value.

```js
const obj = {
   key1: [1, 2, 3],
   key2: [3,4,6]
};

const unsorted = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc.push(...obj[key]);
  return acc;
}, []);

const sorted = [...unsorted].sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: `.sort()` without a comparator will sort as strings. This means that `[1, 2, 10].sort()` is `[1, 10, 2]`

Comment: @VLAZ good catch. it should have a value comparator.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work

```js
    let objects = {
   key1: [1, 2, 3],
   key2: [3,4,6],
   key3: [5, 6, 7],
}
        result = Object.values(objects).join();

console.log(result);
```