# How to apply a function to an object in the chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Below is the code I unsuccessfully try to run in the console of chrome. Now the code of which looks like this and does not actually work.

```
Test.provide = Test.data = function arraaays() {
const c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    if (a[i] !== undefined) {
        c.push(a[i]);
    }

    if (b[i] !== undefined) {
        c.push(b[i]);
    }
}

console.log(c);
}
```

The code itself should interact with two arrays that are in `Test.data` and create a new one of this type on their basis

```
a: ['a', 'b', 'c'] //first array
b: ['d', 'e'] //second array
c: ['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c'] // new array
```

Comment: how are you running that function? and what is `Test` anyway?

Comment: `The code itself should interact with two arrays that are in Test.data` - you've clobbered `Test.data` with the function

Comment: [Possible related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975170/javascript-how-to-join-combine-two-arrays-to-concatenate-into-one-array)

Comment: and, also, the result will actually be `[ "a", "d", "b", "e", "c", undefined ]` - because `undefined !== null`

Comment: @JaromandaX

Data in Test.data

`>Test.data
<{a: Array(10), b: Array(10)}
a: Array(10)
0 :"LfXbYpHqGr"
1:"qCxXsQdYu"
2:"xXlLnIl"
3:"UhHaOa"
4:"Zg"
5:"hIt"
6:"mAkXh"
7:"kDwOqOz"
8:"LlInXvWsVv"
9:"EyIbEzGpSk"
b: Array(10)
0:"mKjRvTf"
1:"Hs"
2:"RmNxQw"
3:"yIxZn"
4:"d"
5:"c"
6:"aAe"
7:"SkIuCbZuZq"
8:"h"
9:"KiTc"`

I do not create objects, I'm working with ready objects. I just need to force the code to interact with the data in the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function arry(a, b) {
var c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    if (a[i] != undefined) {
        c.push(a[i]);
    }

    if (b[i] != undefined) {
        c.push(b[i]);
    }
}
return c;
}
Test.provide = arry(Test.data.a, Test.data.b);
```