# How to concatenate all elements of an array in another without using loop?

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
var arrayPpal = [];
```

with this question I want to know how I can add the elements of other arrays to arrayPpal on the same level without having to perform cycles(without using cycle for, while.)  or something like that.

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var array2 = [8,9,10];
```

the output should be:

```
arrayPpal = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m57axggp/

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: @PrerakSola I tried this Array.prototype.push.apply(); but I want know if there is a best way. in my real project this causes a rare problem..

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/arrays.shtml

Comment: What do you mean by _"without cycles"_ ?

Comment: Just use `concat` method. `let arrayPal=array1.concat(array2)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975170/javascript-how-to-join-combine-two-arrays-to-concatenate-into-one-array ?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia without using cycle for, while.

Comment: @unusuario you mean a loop?

Comment: Oh! you mean loop constructs like `for`, `while`. Just use array's `concat()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [concat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) method.

```
var arrayPpal=[];

var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var array2 = [8,9,10];

arrayPpal = array1.concat(array2);

alert(arrayPpal);
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m57axggp/1/)