# Google Sheets: indexOf() doesn't accept string object

Tags: javascript, csv, google-sheets

I'm trying to filter CSV data by comparing it to an existing google sheet. This is the code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
// get booking ID
var idList=ss.getSheetByName("Umsatzliste").getRange("G:G").getValues();
var filteredCSV=[];
for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ){
    if (idList.indexOf(csvData[i][6].toString())!=-1) {
      filteredCSV.push(csvData[i]);
    }
}
csvData=filteredCSV;
```

The indexOf()-function never seems to work out. csvData is a 2d-array with all csv-values:

```
ss.toast("ID#1: "+idList[0]+" ID#2: "+csvData[2349][6]+" - "+(idList[0]==csvData[2349][6]).toString());
```

returns

```
ID#1: MC/000002674 ID#2: MC/000002674 - false
```

Alright, the typeof reveals they are both "objects", so i try convert the csvData to a string value:

```
ss.toast("ID#1: "+idList[0]+" ID#2: "+csvData[2349][6]+" - "+(idList[0]==csvData[2349][6].toString()).toString());
```

which returns:

```
ID#1: MC/000002674 ID#2: MC/000002674 - true
```

So a comparison works. Any idea why indexOf() doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data `idList` retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. `indexOf()` cannot search the string from 2 dimensional array. So how about the following modification?

### From :

```
if (idList.indexOf(csvData[i][6].toString())!=-1) {
```

### To :

```
if (Array.prototype.concat.apply([], idList).indexOf(csvData[i][6].toString())!=-1) {
```

### Note :

- Using `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], idList)`, 2 dimensional array is converted to 1 dimensional array.

### References :

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [Array.prototype.concat.apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975170/javascript-how-to-join-combine-two-arrays-to-concatenate-into-one-array)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Alright, yea, that makes sense! The first test looks very promising. Thanks a lot!