# Put two different associative arrays inside one associative array as an array with two associative arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I Want to join two arrays into one array containing two different arrays
First Array. I do not mean a simple array but this time around a more complex array with field having the same values on both sides of the arrays.

```js
 var arr1 = [{
  "id": "4",
  "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
  "username": "superuser",
  "password": "$2y$08$awherOdjNPRoDHAiNBGZNuA92UGfT7jsIpsMMcNnyyJMxBA8Ug9q6",
  "salt": null,
  "email": "super@admin.com",
  "activation_code": null,
  "forgotten_password_code": "NULL",
  "forgotten_password_time": null,
  "remember_code": "cBjcajHj8qXaNrOhkAAqPe",
  "created_on": "2018-09-13",
  "last_login": "1540549332",
  "active": "1",
  "first_name": "Super",
  "last_name": "Admin",
  "phone": "0",
  "user_id": "4",
  "groups": [{
    "id": "10",
    "name": "superusers",
    "description": "Super Administrators",
    "$$hashKey": "object:38"
  }],
  "$$hashKey": "object:11"
}];
var arr2 = [{
  "id": "1",
  "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
  "username": "administrator",
  "password": "$2y$08$DoULTzDyGFyh.DTNOvxRtujA3CT2yVBMpp6joYnfUcD0FQgbm9rmy",
  "salt": "",
  "email": "admin@admin.com",
  "activation_code": "",
  "forgotten_password_code": null,
  "forgotten_password_time": null,
  "remember_code": "wYiqzg7AM2QbEPdVrqUhkO",
  "created_on": "2010-03-18",
  "last_login": "1537468397",
  "active": "1",
  "first_name": "Admin",
  "last_name": "istrator",
  "phone": "0",
  "user_id": "1",
  "groups": [{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "admins",
    "description": "Administrators",
    "$$hashKey": "object:32"
  }],
  "$$hashKey": "object:8"
}];
```

Comment: And what have you tried..?

Comment: i have tried object.assign. But its not merging the two of them as different arrays because some of their fields seem to be the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: How to join / combine two arrays to concatenate into one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975170/javascript-how-to-join-combine-two-arrays-to-concatenate-into-one-array)

Comment: Thats not a duplicate @Adriani6

Comment: Yes it is.. you're looking to concatenate two arrays..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const arr1 = [/\*values\*/];

const arr2 = [/\*values\*/];
```

// As in description:

```
const $users = arr1.concat(arr2); //[firstValues, secondValues]
```

// As in title:

```
const $users = [arr1, arr2]; //[[firstValues], [secondValues]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you are genius

Answer (score 1):

let's say you declared your arrays as `arr1` and `arr2`. To merge them:

```
var $users = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

If you want $users to be an array with two elements, and each of one being an array, you would do

```
var $users = [arr1, arr2];
```

But that doesn't match your desired result and it would make little sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot you are genius

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [10, 20];
var b = [30, 40, 50];
Array.prototype.push.apply(a,b);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr1 = [{
  "id": "4",
  "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
  "username": "superuser",
  "password": "$2y$08$awherOdjNPRoDHAiNBGZNuA92UGfT7jsIpsMMcNnyyJMxBA8Ug9q6",
  "salt": null,
  "email": "super@admin.com",
  "activation_code": null,
  "forgotten_password_code": "NULL",
  "forgotten_password_time": null,
  "remember_code": "cBjcajHj8qXaNrOhkAAqPe",
  "created_on": "2018-09-13",
  "last_login": "1540549332",
  "active": "1",
  "first_name": "Super",
  "last_name": "Admin",
  "phone": "0",
  "user_id": "4",
  "groups": [{
    "id": "10",
    "name": "superusers",
    "description": "Super Administrators",
    "$$hashKey": "object:38"
  }],
  "$$hashKey": "object:11"
}];
var arr2 = [{
  "id": "1",
  "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
  "username": "administrator",
  "password": "$2y$08$DoULTzDyGFyh.DTNOvxRtujA3CT2yVBMpp6joYnfUcD0FQgbm9rmy",
  "salt": "",
  "email": "admin@admin.com",
  "activation_code": "",
  "forgotten_password_code": null,
  "forgotten_password_time": null,
  "remember_code": "wYiqzg7AM2QbEPdVrqUhkO",
  "created_on": "2010-03-18",
  "last_login": "1537468397",
  "active": "1",
  "first_name": "Admin",
  "last_name": "istrator",
  "phone": "0",
  "user_id": "1",
  "groups": [{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "admins",
    "description": "Administrators",
    "$$hashKey": "object:32"
  }],
  "$$hashKey": "object:8"
}];
let $users = arr1.concat(arr2);
console.log($users);
```

Concatenate both arrays using `concat` function

Comment: Thanks a lot @sumesh