# How to push all objects of array2 to array1

Tags: arrays, angular

I want to push just the objects of array2 into array1.

```
array1 = [{name:'first'}, {name:'second'}];
array2 = [{name:'third'}, {name:'fourth'}, {name:'five'}];

// Desired result
array1 = [{name:'first'}, {name:'second'}, {name:'third'}, {name:'fourth'}, {name:'five'}];

copyArray() {
   this.array1.push( this.array2 ); 
   this.array2.splice();
}
```

When I run the copyArray function, the array2 itself was instead copied and not the objects. I got this:

**Unwanted result**

```
array1 = [{name:'first'}, {name:'second'}, [{name:'third'}, {name:'fourth'}, {name:'five'}]];
```

Can someone help me to fix this.

Comment: I did that, but array2 was deleting content of array1...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: How to join / combine two arrays to concatenate into one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975170/javascript-how-to-join-combine-two-arrays-to-concatenate-into-one-array)

Comment: just try this.array1.concat(this.array2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spread operator (`...`) makes this easy.

```js
this.array1 = [...this.array1, ...this.array2];
```

Comment: About spread operator, you can use it also inside *push*: `array1.push(...array2);`

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that `push` and `concat` don't change the reference and a lot of Angular change detection relies on variable reference changes for performance reasons. So, the *value* result of `array1.push(...array2)` and my answer above is the same. But mine also changes the reference, making it more likely to be picked up by Angular change detection.

Comment: I have actually tried this before but I was getteing red line under the array2. It was just an editor problem. However, this works thatnks, I think I need the change editor.

Comment: Just one observation: ...this.array1, ...this.array2 is different from ...this.array2, ...this.array1 when using the spread operator with objects, the order determines the result when they have a key with same name with different values

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2sjcw1?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
  copyArray() {
    this.array2.forEach(item => {
      this.array1.push(item);
    });
    this.array2 = [];
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain what this: this.array2 = []; does?

Comment: I assumed you added `this.array2.splice();` to clear array2. `this.array2 = []`; simply make this array empty

Comment: Thanks alot! I used to like your answers.

Comment: You are welcome. The other answer is obviously better :)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you attempted to do. If you want to concatenate two arrays, just use `.concat`:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [4, 5];
const arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);

console.log('arr1', arr1); // unchanged
console.log('arr2', arr2); // unchanged
console.log('arr3', arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper Angular approach is to use combination, you can either use ForkJoin or Concat, more details on [official site](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/).

Answer (score 0):

Proper way is to use the concat function:

```
array2 = array1.concat(array2);
```

It can be use to merge two or more arrays like

```
var result = array1.concat(array2, array3, ..., arrayN);
```