# Javascript: Group Multiple Separate Arrays into One

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this call that returned a response like this:

```
 let pokemonTypes = pokemonData.map((pokemon, i) =>
   {
   let singleType = pokemon.type;
     console.log(singleType);
   }
  );
```

[image]

Please note the arrays are COMPLETELY separate and do not have any parent array or object wrapper.

How can I grab these arrays and wrap them into one or even better concatenate all of their values into one array as in:

```
["fire", "grass", "water", "fire", "grass", "flying"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: How to join / combine two arrays to concatenate into one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975170/javascript-how-to-join-combine-two-arrays-to-concatenate-into-one-array)

Comment: @ASDFGerte    No that is different. These are completely separate arrays...

Comment: @customcommander the returned response after mapping through the object is actually in Json format, except for the arrays are all separate because they all come from different objects

Comment: @customcommander please check the exact response as screenshot from the console...

Comment: @Zeusox It seems to me that you do have references to these arrays; they just live under different namespaces. So you can use `Array#concat` for example

Comment: @customcommander how can I grab or view the references?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to approach this using a function and `reduce`

```
const first = ['bird', 'tiger'];
const second = ['bird'];
const third = ['lion'];
const fourth = ['tiger', 'duck'];

const myFunc = (...args) => {
    return args.reduce((prev, item) => {
        return [...prev, ...item];
    }, [])
}

const result = myFunc(first, second, third, fourth)
console.log(result)
// ["bird", "tiger", "bird", "lion", "tiger", "duck"]
```

https://jsbin.com/picutod/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Please these are completely separate arrays as in I cannot even grab them with their index...

Comment: @Zeusox that doesn't make any sense... You also updated the question significantly since time of writing this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```js
const pokemonData = [{ type: ['Fire'] }, { type: ['Grass', 'Poison'] }]
const types = pokemonData.reduce((acc, {type}) => (acc.push(...type), acc), [])
console.log(types) // [ "Fire", "Grass", "Poison" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to grab them as you get them.

```js
let allPokemonTypes = [];

function onNewPokemonType(pokemonTypes) {
    console.log(pokemonTypes);
    allPokemonTypes = [...allPokemonTypes, ...pokemonTypes];
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: That function just represents what should happen when you get your pokemon types. When you get a new one, you can add the elements to an array. This way you'll have them all together