# How can I add elements of an array not the array itself?

Tags: javascript

I have an first array and the second array with elements I want to add to the first array

```
arr1 = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
arr2 = [ 4, 5, 6 ];

arr1.push(arr2);  // [ 1, 2, 3, [ 4, 5, 6]]  but i need [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is likely what you want to use

Comment: arr1.concat(arr2);

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+merge+two+arrays) of [JavaScript: How to join / combine two arrays to concatenate into one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975179/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either, modify the array and use [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2)
```

Or, [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
arr1.push(...arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with spread operator:

```
arr1 = [...arr1, ...arr2];
```